# PHP | Current page URI switcher | "Pagination"

Tags: php, uri, href

[image: Visual]

> I'm attempting to make a quick page switcher for different models of the same product. This would be hard to implement if it had to be done individually, so I'm making it with some PHP.
>
> There is a single folder with all the Models for each product, the problem is correctly sorting them, the pages are already created with each one. Each model has its own folder inside of the product folder and ends with a number.

They all fall within two types of URI's

`../product-name/###` or `../product-name/title-###`

So I'm trying to write a PHP script that would take the current page's URI's `###`, the next lowest/highest `###`, and set them as the `href` for either arrow.

If there is no next lowest/highest `###` then set the arrow transparency to 0 (can be done with a `class` if necessary.

The `Current Page` would fill with the current page's `<title>`

*Can someone at least point me in the right direction? Any and all help is greatly appreciated!*

> UPDATE: Thanks to @gumbo I now know that this is called pagination, if anyone knows of a Pre-built script that works at least very similar to this please let me know, THANKS!!
>
> PS: I'm eventually moving everything over to wordpress, so if that would make it much easier then I'll just wait.

Comment: This is called [pagination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination). Try searching for [“\[php\] pagination”](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+pagination).

Comment: Where do you keep the lowest-highest values for the ### product?

Comment: in the model folder title `/[product]/[model-title?]-[ends with ###]/index.html`

Comment: I'm trying to base this off the folder tree not a database or anything since this already exists.

Comment: So you need to know to contents of this folder to decide the boundaries. Of course you can do this but will be a little messy I think. It would be better if you had this info in a DB. You can check this [link](http://www.sitepoint.com/perfect-php-pagination/) for a little more insight about pagination.

Comment: Also you can use [scandir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) function to read the contents of the folder.

Comment: @osoner I know this would be a bit messy, but its for a small company and the IT guy is going to be managing this, which he understands nothing about so I'm trying to make everything easy on him. -- Thanks for that link!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you'd like to access the contents of a directory and sort through the files.

```
<?php
$dir_handle = opendir('./');

while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {

if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {?>

<span><?php echo $file?></span><br />

<?php }
}
closedir($dir_handle);
?>
```

That should give you a start.  Use basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']); to retrieve the name of the current script.  Perhaps the next step would be to extract that current script's ### and replace the span element in the above example with a test against each file.